# Is it possible to copy the filtered cells

Tags: excel

What I've encountered is that after filtering the 'E9' cell, I would like to copy the values of 'D', 'F', and 'G' cells. But when i copy them, it end up copying the hidden cells as well. I only want to copy the filtered cells and not the ones that are hidden. Other than that, I would like to make it a loop so that instead of hard copying the code, I can make it a loop so that it can search for the next filtered cell. Instead of copying all of cell 'D', I only want to copy 'D31', 'D68', 'D105',..... and so on. Are there any ways on coding it as I'm still new to macros so I would like to have some of yours assistance, thank you.

```
Sub trial()

Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wb3 As Workbook
Dim fn As String

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
.AllowMultiSelect = False
If .Show = -1 Then
fn = .SelectedItems(1)
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(fn)
Else
MsgBox "You cancel the process."
Exit Sub
End If
End With

Dim ws As Worksheet

    wb2.Activate

    Application.DecimalSeparator = ","
    Application.ThousandsSeparator = "."
    Application.UseSystemSeparators = True

    Sheets(1).AutoFilterMode = False
    Sheets(1).Range("$A$9:$P$417").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
        "1,000,000"
    Range("F31:F804").Select
    Selection.Copy
    wb.Activate

    'determine the sheet you want to copy to and search for the next empty row
    'change the commas to dot as well
    Sheets(2).Activate

        Dim FirstCell As String
        Dim i As Integer
            FirstCell = "D19"
            Range(FirstCell).Select
            Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
            If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
            Exit Do
            Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
            Loop


    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True

    wb2.Activate
    Range("D31:D804").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wb.Activate

    'determine the sheet you want to copy to and search for the next empty row
    Sheets(3).Activate

            FirstCell = "D19"
            Range(FirstCell).Select
            Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
            If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
            Exit Do
            Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
            Loop


    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    wb2.Activate
    Range("G31:G804").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wb.Activate

    'determine the sheet you want to copy to and search for the next empty row
    Sheets(4).Activate


    FirstCell = "D19"
            Range(FirstCell).Select
            Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
            If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
            Exit Do
            Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
            Loop


    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    wb2.Close

End Sub
```

[This is the link to the image for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIYXd.png)

Comment: Sorry that i didn't mention earlier in the post.. I hope to do it in macros as well not manually.. Really sorry about that

Comment: Sp starting at cell `D31`, you are copying every 37th cell, no? Where are you copying the cells to? What is the destination?

Comment: Yes it's every 37th cell for this worksheet only.. But if i were to switch worksheet, it might not be the same anymore.. So hard coding it is kinda like a no already.. Is it possible if I loop it? For example, after filtering the column, excel will copy the filtered cells ('D31', 'D68', 'D105',.....) one by one over to another workbook... I can't use use range in this case as it will also copy the hidden cells.. @dwirony

Answer (score 0):

To copy only visible cells select the range you would like to copy and then press alt ; (that is the alt key, and semicolon key)

If you need additional help feel free to ask. Also, I found a link that may help you as well: https://www.excelcampus.com/keyboard-shortcuts/copy-paste-select-visible-cells/

Answer (score 0):

To copy Unhidden cells,

a. Click ALT+; and then do CTRL+c

b. Home tab --> Find&SELECT --> Go to special --> Visible cells only

Comment: Any idea how to do it using macros ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23010213/vba-code-to-filter-data-and-create-a-new-sheet-and-transfer-data-to-it

Comment: thank you for sharing the link... the macros he coded uses range to determine the cells he wants to copy.. but for my case i can't use range as it will copy the hidden files as well.. is it possible if i use loop to copy one by one ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply copy visible cells in macros you can record you doing the alt semicolon that was described earlier and then copy. End the macro recording and save it with some assigned name.

Comment: have tried doing that as well... but the macros will be hard codded.. would want a flexi one so that any file can be selected to be able to run with the macros instead of that one particular file.. other than that, the reason i want to use a loop is because from what i recorded, after highlighting the cells i want ( 'D31', 'D68', 'D105',.....) it doesn't copy those particular cells only.. it also copies the ones that are not listed.. meaning it turn out to be range instead of those selected cells only

Answer (score 0):

```
Worksheets("YourSheet").AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

This code allows you to copy only the filtered cells i.e. the ones visible when a filtered is applied. This will help you accomplish what you want and will not copy the hidden cells you don't need.

Comment: Try to add some commentary explaining your answer or it is likely to be flagged for deletion.